# Identify unknown ASN.1 Objects

Tags: content-management-system, analysis, x509, asn.1, der

We searched for DER-encoded SEQUENCE's in an executable. After cherrpicking those, which looked like valid DER-encoded data, we wanted to analyse how they are used.

X.509 Certificates and CMS Objects were easy to recognize (since we are aware of them), but we also found valid encodings, from which we cant tell what they are used for.

E.g. Have a look at the following output of `openssl asn1parse (...)`:

---

```
    0:d=0  hl=4 l=1804 cons: SEQUENCE          
    4:d=1  hl=2 l=   1 prim:  INTEGER           :03
    7:d=1  hl=4 l=1797 cons:  SEQUENCE          
   11:d=2  hl=2 l=  20 cons:   SEQUENCE          
   13:d=3  hl=2 l=   8 prim:    OBJECT            :des-ede3-cbc
   23:d=3  hl=2 l=   8 prim:    OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:0000000000000000
   33:d=2  hl=2 l=   3 prim:   PRINTABLESTRING   :<OMITTED>
   38:d=2  hl=2 l=  13 prim:   UTCTIME           :<OMITTED>
   53:d=2  hl=2 l=   1 prim:   INTEGER           :01
   56:d=2  hl=4 l=1748 cons:   SET               
   60:d=3  hl=4 l= 830 cons:    SEQUENCE          
   64:d=4  hl=2 l=   6 prim:     PRINTABLESTRING   :PKRoot
   72:d=4  hl=2 l=  13 prim:     UTCTIME           :<OMITTED>
   87:d=4  hl=2 l=   5 prim:     OBJECT            :1.3.36.2.5.1
   94:d=4  hl=4 l= 796 cons:     SEQUENCE          
   98:d=5  hl=2 l=  69 cons:      SEQUENCE          
  100:d=6  hl=2 l=  11 cons:       SET               
  102:d=7  hl=2 l=   9 cons:        SEQUENCE          
  104:d=8  hl=2 l=   3 prim:         OBJECT            :countryName
  109:d=8  hl=2 l=   2 prim:         PRINTABLESTRING   :<OMITTED>
  113:d=6  hl=2 l=  31 cons:       SET               
  115:d=7  hl=2 l=  29 cons:        SEQUENCE          
  117:d=8  hl=2 l=   3 prim:         OBJECT            :organizationName
  122:d=8  hl=2 l=  22 prim:         PRINTABLESTRING   :<OMITTED>
  146:d=6  hl=2 l=  21 cons:       SET               
  148:d=7  hl=2 l=  19 cons:        SEQUENCE          
  150:d=8  hl=2 l=   3 prim:         OBJECT            :commonName
  155:d=8  hl=2 l=  12 prim:         PRINTABLESTRING   :<OMITTED>
  169:d=5  hl=4 l= 614 cons:      SEQUENCE          
  173:d=6  hl=2 l=   3 cons:       cont [ 0 ]        
  175:d=7  hl=2 l=   1 prim:        INTEGER           :02
  178:d=6  hl=2 l=   1 prim:       INTEGER           :00
  181:d=6  hl=4 l= 290 cons:       SEQUENCE          
  185:d=7  hl=2 l=  13 cons:        SEQUENCE          
  187:d=8  hl=2 l=   9 prim:         OBJECT            :rsaEncryption
  198:d=8  hl=2 l=   0 prim:         NULL              
  200:d=7  hl=4 l= 271 prim:        BIT STRING        
  475:d=6  hl=2 l=  32 cons:       cont [ 1 ]        
  477:d=7  hl=2 l=  30 cons:        SEQUENCE          
  479:d=8  hl=2 l=  13 prim:         UTCTIME           :<OMITTED>
  494:d=8  hl=2 l=  13 prim:         UTCTIME           :<OMITTED>
  509:d=6  hl=2 l=  15 cons:       cont [ 2 ]        
  511:d=7  hl=2 l=  13 cons:        SEQUENCE          
  513:d=8  hl=2 l=   9 prim:         OBJECT            :sha256WithRSAEncryption
  524:d=8  hl=2 l=   0 prim:         NULL              
  526:d=6  hl=4 l= 257 prim:       BIT STRING        
  787:d=5  hl=2 l= 105 cons:      cont [ 0 ]        
  789:d=6  hl=2 l= 103 cons:       SEQUENCE          
  791:d=7  hl=2 l=  15 cons:        SEQUENCE          
  793:d=8  hl=2 l=   3 prim:         OBJECT            :X509v3 Basic Constraints
  798:d=8  hl=2 l=   1 prim:         BOOLEAN           :255
  801:d=8  hl=2 l=   5 prim:         OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:<OMITTED>
  808:d=7  hl=2 l=  37 cons:        SEQUENCE          
  810:d=8  hl=2 l=   3 prim:         OBJECT            :X509v3 Subject Alternative Name
  815:d=8  hl=2 l=  30 prim:         OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:<OMITTED>
  847:d=7  hl=2 l=  14 cons:        SEQUENCE          
  849:d=8  hl=2 l=   3 prim:         OBJECT            :X509v3 Key Usage
  854:d=8  hl=2 l=   1 prim:         BOOLEAN           :255
  857:d=8  hl=2 l=   4 prim:         OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:<OMITTED>
  863:d=7  hl=2 l=  29 cons:        SEQUENCE          
  865:d=8  hl=2 l=   3 prim:         OBJECT            :X509v3 Subject Key Identifier
  870:d=8  hl=2 l=  22 prim:         OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:<OMITTED>
  894:d=3  hl=4 l= 910 cons:    SEQUENCE          
  898:d=4  hl=2 l=   4 prim:     PRINTABLESTRING   :Cert
  904:d=4  hl=2 l=  13 prim:     UTCTIME           :<OMITTED>
  919:d=4  hl=2 l=   5 prim:     OBJECT            :1.3.36.2.1.3
  926:d=4  hl=4 l= 878 cons:     SEQUENCE          
  930:d=5  hl=4 l= 598 cons:      SEQUENCE          
  934:d=6  hl=2 l=   3 cons:       cont [ 0 ]        
  936:d=7  hl=2 l=   1 prim:        INTEGER           :02
  939:d=6  hl=2 l=   1 prim:       INTEGER           :00
  942:d=6  hl=2 l=  13 cons:       SEQUENCE          
  944:d=7  hl=2 l=   9 prim:        OBJECT            :sha256WithRSAEncryption
  955:d=7  hl=2 l=   0 prim:        NULL              
  957:d=6  hl=2 l=  69 cons:       SEQUENCE          
  959:d=7  hl=2 l=  11 cons:        SET               
  961:d=8  hl=2 l=   9 cons:         SEQUENCE          
  963:d=9  hl=2 l=   3 prim:          OBJECT            :countryName
  968:d=9  hl=2 l=   2 prim:          PRINTABLESTRING   :<OMITTED>
  972:d=7  hl=2 l=  31 cons:        SET               
  974:d=8  hl=2 l=  29 cons:         SEQUENCE          
  976:d=9  hl=2 l=   3 prim:          OBJECT            :organizationName
  981:d=9  hl=2 l=  22 prim:          PRINTABLESTRING   :<OMITTED>
 1005:d=7  hl=2 l=  21 cons:        SET               
 1007:d=8  hl=2 l=  19 cons:         SEQUENCE          
 1009:d=9  hl=2 l=   3 prim:          OBJECT            :commonName
 1014:d=9  hl=2 l=  12 prim:          PRINTABLESTRING   :<OMITTED>
 1028:d=6  hl=2 l=  30 cons:       SEQUENCE          
 1030:d=7  hl=2 l=  13 prim:        UTCTIME           :<OMITTED>
 1045:d=7  hl=2 l=  13 prim:        UTCTIME           :<OMITTED>
 1060:d=6  hl=2 l=  69 cons:       SEQUENCE          
 1062:d=7  hl=2 l=  11 cons:        SET               
 1064:d=8  hl=2 l=   9 cons:         SEQUENCE          
 1066:d=9  hl=2 l=   3 prim:          OBJECT            :countryName
 1071:d=9  hl=2 l=   2 prim:          PRINTABLESTRING   :<OMITTED>
 1075:d=7  hl=2 l=  31 cons:        SET               
 1077:d=8  hl=2 l=  29 cons:         SEQUENCE          
 1079:d=9  hl=2 l=   3 prim:          OBJECT            :organizationName
 1084:d=9  hl=2 l=  22 prim:          PRINTABLESTRING   :<OMITTED>
 1108:d=7  hl=2 l=  21 cons:        SET               
 1110:d=8  hl=2 l=  19 cons:         SEQUENCE          
 1112:d=9  hl=2 l=   3 prim:          OBJECT            :commonName
 1117:d=9  hl=2 l=  12 prim:          PRINTABLESTRING   :<OMITTED>
 1131:d=6  hl=4 l= 290 cons:       SEQUENCE          
 1135:d=7  hl=2 l=  13 cons:        SEQUENCE          
 1137:d=8  hl=2 l=   9 prim:         OBJECT            :rsaEncryption
 1148:d=8  hl=2 l=   0 prim:         NULL              
 1150:d=7  hl=4 l= 271 prim:        BIT STRING        
 1425:d=6  hl=2 l= 105 cons:       cont [ 3 ]        
 1427:d=7  hl=2 l= 103 cons:        SEQUENCE          
 1429:d=8  hl=2 l=  15 cons:         SEQUENCE          
 1431:d=9  hl=2 l=   3 prim:          OBJECT            :X509v3 Basic Constraints
 1436:d=9  hl=2 l=   1 prim:          BOOLEAN           :255
 1439:d=9  hl=2 l=   5 prim:          OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:<OMITTED>
 1446:d=8  hl=2 l=  37 cons:         SEQUENCE          
 1448:d=9  hl=2 l=   3 prim:          OBJECT            :X509v3 Subject Alternative Name
 1453:d=9  hl=2 l=  30 prim:          OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:<OMITTED>
 1485:d=8  hl=2 l=  14 cons:         SEQUENCE          
 1487:d=9  hl=2 l=   3 prim:          OBJECT            :X509v3 Key Usage
 1492:d=9  hl=2 l=   1 prim:          BOOLEAN           :255
 1495:d=9  hl=2 l=   4 prim:          OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:<OMITTED>
 1501:d=8  hl=2 l=  29 cons:         SEQUENCE          
 1503:d=9  hl=2 l=   3 prim:          OBJECT            :X509v3 Subject Key Identifier
 1508:d=9  hl=2 l=  22 prim:          OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:<OMITTED>
 1532:d=5  hl=2 l=  13 cons:      SEQUENCE          
 1534:d=6  hl=2 l=   9 prim:       OBJECT            :sha256WithRSAEncryption
 1545:d=6  hl=2 l=   0 prim:       NULL              
 1547:d=5  hl=4 l= 257 prim:      BIT STRING
```

---

Does anybody recognize, which ASN.1 type maps to this?

Of course, there are some patterns (e.g. at offset 98 or 930) which are easy to recognize, but is there any "clever" way of identifying unknown ASN.1 structures?

Special Google search-patterns, websites, software, etc.?

We tried Google searches like `* ::= SEQUENCE { * INTEGER }` etc., with no success.

Comment: *Does anybody recognize, which ASN.1 type maps to this?* - Some people might have tried harder to identify if you had shared the binary to download somewhere...

Comment: yes, binary copy would be better.

Comment: Since the data could contain information our customer does not want to be published, we stripped some of it -- It would be easier thought, sorry for that.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this: http://www.oid-info.com/get/1.3.36.2.1

oid-info.com currently has over 950.000 OID's, but it has your OID in question up to the level 1.3.36.

Therefore, by querying this service starting from 1.3.36 will give you the that this OID is registered by

```
TeleTrusT - IT Security Association Germany
```

and querying with 1.3.36.2 will tell you that it is a

```
Security information object
```

and with 1.3.36.2.1 will tell you that this is a

```
Certificate
```

However, there is no information on 1.3.36.2.5.1 or 1.3.36.2.1.3, this is because it doesn't have to, because once 1.3.36 is registered by TeleTrust, they have overall ownership on the sub nodes.

I don't know if the registration office has a service to let you query among all registered OID's, but for now, odi-info has some 1 million OID's queryable.

Comment: Oh thanks. Very helpful! Of course, there are no ASN.1 definitions available :-/, but I asked TeleTrust weather they can provide them.

Answer (score 0):

To me, this dump looks like a sort of PKCS#7 message (but it is not PKCS#7). There is no universal way to bind raw data to arbitrary ASN object without ASN module. You may need to create your own tables, map raw data to them and see which table succeed. It is not that easy without knowing each message semantic (which is defined in the ASN module). If you are on Windows, you can try the following command:

`certutil -dump path\fileWithUnknownAsn.ext`

Certutil has several built-in tables to represent common X509 objects and, maybe, it shows you what is that.

Comment: No luck with `certutil`. It just dumps the whole file with no additional information...

Comment: I can't tell what exactly it is. I see two envolepes. First envelope points to symmetric algorithm and (possible) encrypted data under OCTET_STRING. Outer SET contains 2 objects: several components similar to X.509 certificate, but it is not a certificate, and X.509 certificate. Sorry, I can't identify the object based on this dump.